# In Ajax, I want to use "a selected option" as a file name in another php file

Tags: javascript, php

First, please, let's see my html code

```
 <select name="lang" id="lang">
    <option value="ko">한국어</option>
    <option value="en">English</option>

    <option value="af">Afrikaans</option>
 </select>

 <form>
 <input type="text" size="30" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)">
 <div id="livesearch"></div>
 </form>
```

and, javascript code below

```
 <script>
 function showResult(str)
 {
 if (str.length==0)
 { 
   .....
 {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
 ....
  }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","livesearch.php?q="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
 </script>
```

Above script code, there is livesearch.php?...
So, livesearch.php code is below.

```
 <?php
 $file=$_GET['name'];
 $xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
 $xmlDoc->load("ds_".$file.".xml");

 $x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('link');

  //get the q parameter from URL
   $q=$_GET["q"];

  //lookup all links from the xml file if length of q>0
  if (strlen($q)>0)
  {
    $hint="";
 for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++)
 {
 $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title');
 $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');
 if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1)
```

-->> Can I use '$file' variable from the select-option html code??
Otherwise, another way?? 
please help me??

Comment: Not too sure what is going on here... Did you just paste code and forget to ask the question?

Comment: Where is your relevant php code? I don't see anywhere where you are receiving the value. e.g $_GET?

Comment: Sorry!  last sentence is omitted.

Comment: I want a selected option in html code, which is active in the livesearch.php file whose has ds_en.xml(not .php--sorry!!). Can 'en' be a selected option value in livesearch.html code

Comment: 'q' is livesearch input typing. What i want is the selected option value (<select name="lang" ...> -> here, 'lang' is a variable. On Select-Option click, in livesearch.php, can the ds_".$file.".xml be changeable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear on what you want, but it sounds like you want the value to be the name of a file. You will need to get the value of the ajax request. **Here is just an example.**

```
<?php

     $file = $_GET["q"];
     //you can use $file wherever you want.

     $xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
     $xmlDoc->load("ds_".$file.".php .xml");

     $x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('link');
```

Comment: 'q' is livesearch input typing. What i want is the selected option value (<select name="lang" ...> -> here, 'lang' is a variable. On Select-Option click, in livesearch.php, can the ds_".$file.".xml be changeable?

Answer (score 0):

That should be easy, assuming your PHP was correct:

```
<?php
// function for input validation
// returns only valid input, defaults to 'en' when given invalid input
function validate($str) {
    if (in_array($str, array('en', 'ko', 'af', 'etc.'))) {
        return $str;
    }
    return 'en'; // default case for invalid input
}

// create DOMDocument
$xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();

// check if the URL parameter was set
if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
    // just add the validated input string in here
    $xmlDoc->load('ds_' . validate($_GET['q']) . '.php .xml');
} else {
    // invalid URL parameter
    die('error');
}
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('link');
```

To clarify: If you want input from the URL parameters, use `$_GET`, which is an array.